# How do I differentiate between an empty window text and an error with the GetWindowText API?

Tags: windows, winapi

The `GetWindowText` function's return value is [documented as follows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the length, in
>   characters, of the copied string, not including the terminating null
>   character. If the window has no title bar or text, if the title bar is
>   empty, or if the window or control handle is invalid, the return value
>   is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

Now, when calling this method and receiving a return value of zero, how do I know whether `GetLastError` would return a sensible value? After all, zero is not only used to indicate failure, but could also mean that the window text is empty, in which case `GetLastError` would not return an undefined value.

My own ideas:

- At first, I thought that maybe `GetWindowText` might set the last error to 0 on success. But testing shows it doesn't (and if it did, I couldn't rely on it anyway, since this isn't documented).
- Then, I thought that maybe `GetWindowText` might leave the last error unchanged on success, so setting it to 0 myself before the call would allow me to check whether the last error has changed. Testing shows this might work, but since it's not doumented this way, I can't rely on it. (And I guess this would depend heavily on the concrete circumstances and implementation of `GetWindowText`.)
- And, of course, I could first check the window text length using `GetWindowTextLength` and then call `GetWindowText` only if the length was greater than 0. However, what if the window changes its text between my calls to `GetWindowTextLength` and `GetWindowText`? I, again, couldn't rely on a return value of zero denoting an error.

So, what can I do to definitely decide whether `GetWindowText` failed?

Comment: I'm afraid, that the only way to control a window in full degree is to subclass it first and then monitor all possible events related to text changes (if any) and window existence. Without this you can only rely on a half measures, such as you mentioned: cleaning last error flag, reading text length, plus checking the window handle for validity beforehand by means of `IsWindow`. All of these lacks transactional consistency though. This looks like a flaw in the API.

Comment: Note if the window you are trying to read its text from is in another process, the call will always succeed by design. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/08/21/54675.aspx

Comment: Well, it could still fail because of a bad handle or something, couldn't it?

Answer (score 4):

`SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS)` beforehand is perfectly safe and supported.

The documentation for last-error codes make it clear that a function may or may not clear the last-error value on success.  What is certain, however, is that if a function succeeds, it will either leave the last-error value unchanged, or set it to zero, but never change it to an error value.

The implementation rules for WinAPI functions may be summarized as:

1. Don't call `SetLastError` if no error occurs.
2. If a helper function sets an error code, which does not cause failure of your API, call `SetLastError(0)` so the non-fatal internal error isn't visible to the caller, [or call `RestoreLastError` and pass whatever `GetLastError` returned on entry to your API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/29/10159322.aspx)
3. If your API fails without throwing an SEH exception, call `SetLastError` to report it (unless a helper function already did).

The documented behavior "some functions call `SetLastError` with a zero when they succeed" is a consequence of point #2.

Comment: Sounds good, can you point me to a documentation source for point #2? `GetWindowText` calling an API which sets an error code, but does not cause the failure of `GetWindowText` was exactly what I was thinking about.

Comment: @Fabian: It's in [the documentation of `GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx).  It mentions that some functions may set the code to 0 on success while others don't set it.  Nowhere is any function permitted to set the last error code to any failure code if they succeed.

Comment: I don't see that the docs for `GetLastError` require the helper function to either set the last error to 0 or to restore it in case of success. The docs say, "If the function is not documented to set the last-error code, the value [...] is simply the most recent last-error code to have been set; some functions set the last-error code to 0 on success and others do not."

Comment: The question is what "most recent" means. Most recent _before_ the call of the "function" (that would be good for solving my problem), or just most recent - i.e., might as well have been set by a helper function while executing the called function. Just from the wording, I can't rely on the former, so I must assume the latter.

(BTW, the RestoreLastError function is not documented on MSDN, so it's probably not a good idea to use it.)

Comment: (However, of course, they probably use it internally, so please ignore my comment above about RestoreLastError not being documented.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, you cannot actually use `GetLastError()` to see the difference.  Not pretty.  The only workaround I can think of is to use `IsWindow()` afterward.  If that returns TRUE then a zero return really means "empty string".  That, however, doesn't deal with passing a bad buffer pointer, hopefully easily avoided in your code.

Comment: Perhaps slightly pedantic, but `IsWindow` is not guaranteed to do what is expected in this case because of handle recycling.

Comment: Hmya, this cannot be a consideration.  All bets are off anyway if the handle gets recycled *before* calling GetWindowText().